# Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Tags: java

Why is Eclipse keeps giving me error on the constructor:

```
 public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length);
  }
```

The error is:`Implicit super constructor Board() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Class **DenseBoard**

```
package Game2048;

// Tracks the positions of an arbitrary 2D grid of Tiles.  DenseBoard
// uses an internal, multi-dimensional array to store the tiles and
// thus has a O(R * C) memory footprint (rows by columns).
public class DenseBoard extends Board {

  // Build a Board of the specified size that is empty of any tiles
  public DenseBoard(int rows, int cols){
      super(rows, cols);
  }

  // Build a board that copies the 2D array of tiles provided Tiles
  // are immutable so can be referenced without copying but the a
  // fresh copy of the 2D array must be created for internal use by
  // the Board.
  public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length);
  }
```

Class **Board**

```
package Game2048;

public abstract class Board{

  protected int rows;
  protected int cols;


  public Board(int rows, int cols){
      this.rows = rows;
      this.cols = cols;
  }
  // Create a distinct copy of the board including its internal tile
  // positions and any other state
  public abstract Board copy();

  // Return the number of rows in the Board
  public abstract int getRows();

  // Return the number of columns in the Board
  public abstract int getCols();

  // Return how many tiles are present in the board (non-empty spaces)
  public abstract int getTileCount();

  // Return how many free spaces are in the board
  public abstract int getFreeSpaceCount();

  // Get the tile at a particular location
  public abstract Tile tileAt(int i, int j);

  // true if the last shift operation moved any tile; false otherwise
  public abstract boolean lastShiftMovedTiles();

  // Return true if a shift left, right, up, or down would merge any
  // tiles. If no shift would cause any tiles to merge, return false.
  // The inability to merge anything is part of determining if the
  // game is over.
  public abstract boolean mergePossible();

  // Add a the given tile to the board at the "freeI"th free space.
  public abstract void addTileAtFreeSpace(int freeI, Tile tile);

  // Shift the tiles of Board in various directions.  Any tiles that
  // collide and should be merged should be changed internally in the
  // board.  Shifts only remove tiles, never add anything.  The shift
  // methods also set the state of the board internally so that a
  // subsequent call to lastShiftMovedTiles() will return true if any
  // Tile moved and false otherwise.  The methods return the score
  // that is generated from the shift which is the sum of the scores
  // all tiles merged during the shift. If no tiles are merged, the
  // return score is 0.
  public abstract int shiftLeft();
  public abstract int shiftRight();
  public abstract int shiftUp();
  public abstract int shiftDown();

}
```

Comment: why are you doing this `Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length);`

Comment: @Shahzeb, what should I do then?

Comment: `super(t.length, t[0].length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this to send the values up to parent class.

```
public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      super(t.length, t[0].length);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this

```
public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      this(t.length, t[0].length);
 }
```

Comment: Why `this`, @IvoBeckers? What does `this` refer to ?

Comment: `this` calls the other constructor of DenseBoard. Alternatively you could do `super(t.length, t[0].length);` since you don't do anything special in the other constructor

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out

```
public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]) {
    Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length);
}
```

`myBoard` is local variable, you will not be able to refer it when you create a new object using `new DenseBoard(Tile t[][])`.

---

You can do it in 2 ways.

```
public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]) {
    super(t.length, t[0].length); // calling super class constructor
}

// or
// I would prefer this
public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]) {
    this(t.length, t[0].length); // calling DenseBoard(int rows, int cols) constuctor, which is internally passing the value to super class.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Board` you only have one constructor which requires 2 `int` arguments.

And since `DenseBoard` extends `Board`, each of the constructor in `DenseBoard` should call some constructor in `Board`.

If `Board` had a no-arg constructor, the compiler would automatically call it for you. But since you don't have one, you should call another constructor explicitly from your `public DenseBoard(Tile t[][])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to call the constructor of the superclass. If the superclass had defined a no-argument constructor, you would not be seeing this error. To expand on the other answers with some code, what you need is

```
 public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      //You need a way to figure meaningful values to the superconstructor here
      super(intVar1, intVar2);
      Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length); //I think 
     //this now becomes unnecessary?
  }
```

Or alternatively modify your `Board` class to include

```
public Board()
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you DenseBoard class should implement all the Board class's abstract method. 
such like this:

```
package Game2048;
public class DenseBoard extends Board {

  public DenseBoard(int rows, int cols){
      super(rows, cols);
  }

  public DenseBoard(Tile t[][]){
      Board myBoard = new DenseBoard(t.length, t[0].length);
  }

  public Board copy(){

  }

  public int getRows(){

  }

  public int getCols(){

  }

  public int getTileCount(){

  }

  public int getFreeSpaceCount(){

  }

  public Tile tileAt(int i, int j){

  }

  public boolean lastShiftMovedTiles(){

  }

  public boolean mergePossible(){

  }

  public void addTileAtFreeSpace(int freeI, Tile tile){

  }

  public int shiftLeft(){

  }

  public int shiftRight(){

  }

  public int shiftUp(){

  }

  public int shiftDown(){

  }
}
```